# How to auto generate <md:NameIDFormat>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:emailAddress</md:NameIDFormat> in Shibboleth SSO login Metadata file

Tags: single-sign-on, saml-2.0, shibboleth, shibboleth-sp

I have done all shibboleth related configuration at my server. After Shibboleth.sso/Status getting Ok Status and after Shibboleth.sso/Metadata, metadata file is downloading but
tag is not present in generated Metadata file so I want to know below things:
1)What changes I need to add in Shibboleth2.xml file.
2)Where Exact I need to do change in Shibboleth2.xml file.
So after downloading metadata file
this tag will auto generated in metadata file.
I have added below changes in Shibboleth2.xml file.
Service restart then download the file nut still NameId format tag is not generating.